# Catch an Error on html with php

Tags: php, html, forms

currently i'm developing a website in a class in my university. i'm using PHP and MySQL.

i have the signup page that when submitted goes to a auxiliary php page that goes through a number of conditions and i'f the form failed in one of the conditions i wanted to return to the signup page that also appeared a line detailing the error.

i wanted to know if i only need to use php or php+javascript.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get extra points you could use both!

Add the [JQuery validate plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqueryvalidate) to your form. This will display real time errors to the user. You can't totally rely on this method though because if the user switches off JS then the validation wornt work ;)

In your PHP run through your validation checks and if one fails then use header (as phpNutt mention above) but I wouldn't recommend passing the error message in the URL as this can look unprofessional. Instead a number, then just check for the number on the signup page. If it's there *then* display the error.

```
// auxiliary php page  
if (conditon met) { 

} else {
    header("location: /signup_page.php?error=1");
    exit; 
} 

// signup page 
if(isset($_GET['error']) && $_GET['error']==1) { 
echo "<h3>Form Failed, please try again</h3>"; 
}
```

Comment: this would be great but i'm not allowed to use libraries in this work.
but i'll see the signup code and see how it works... thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could just do a [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) redirect in your else condition and attach the error message as a GET parameter. Then show the error message on the signup_page.php. See code example below:

```
if (conditon met) {

} else {
    header("location: /signup_page.php?error=".urlencode("Form Failed, please try again"));
    exit;
}
```